# (expl3) Expand the result of a function in a definition

Tags: expandafter, def

If I do that:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}
 {
    [ \fp_eval:n { #1 } ] 
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
...
\edef\bar{\foo{#1} }
\edef\baz{\foo{#1+1} }
```

if the argument `#1` is 42, and if I write:

```
\typeout{\bar}
\typeout{\baz}
```

I obtain :

```
\foo{42}
\foo{42+1}
```

while I would like to obtain the result of `foo`, that is to say:

```
[42]
[43]
```

Surely a question of `expandafter` that I ignore?

How have I to process?

**EDIT:**

Ok, sorry, I didn't know that `NewDocumentCommand` was `protected`. I just have discovered expl3... Thank you for your help, guys.  `NewExpandableDocumentCommand` works fine.

**EDIT (2):**

As @wipet blew it to me, we can simply write:

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
[\the\numexpr #1\relax ]%
}
```

Comment: You probably need `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand` defined commands are `\protected` and do not expand in `\edef` so `\edef\bar{\foo{#1} }` is just `\def\bar{\foo{#1} }`

Comment: By the way, there already is `\fpeval`.

Comment: By the way, there already is `\numexpr`.

Comment: Oh, yes, for sure, @wipet. I just have been editing my post for adding this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macros defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are `\protected`, so they won't expand in `\edef`. You need

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}...
```

Of course, if you want to use `\foo` in `\edef`, its action must be fully expandable (which is the case in the particular example).

By the way, `\fp_eval:n` is overkill if you just want arithmetic on integers and the LaTeX kernel provides the `expl3` function `\int_eval:n` but also the user level macro `\inteval`.

You can do, without `\ExplSyntaxOn`,

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{%
  [\inteval{#1}]%
}
```

and

```
\edef\baz{\foo{#1+1}}
```

would result in `\baz` expanding to `[43]`.

I contend that `\inteval{42+1}` is clearer than `\the\numexpr42+1\relax`.